# Организовать избранное PHP

Tags: алгоритм, php

Не подумайте, что я какой-то велосипедостроитель. Просто в меру того, что у определенных задач нету и не будет никогда стандартных решений задаю следующий вопрос.
Допустим есть небольшой каталог товаров, пусть будут гостиницы. Человек пришел на сайт и смотрит их. Понятное дело, что если он пришел впервые то все, что он мне как посетитель подарил это открытую сессию и если надо и то не всегда - печеньку. Так вот допустим организация избранного для зарегистрированного пользователя проходит прям через товар. т.е. есть мультисвойство в которое вписывается ID пользователя отметившего товар. Как бы вы поступили с анонимным пользователем? Понятно, что когда он захочет авторизоваться надо его гостинницы их избранного слить в его авторизированый список. В общем хотел мнения специалистов.

Comment: Вот. Довели людей. Теперь боятся строить велосипеды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Завел бы запись в бд, с новым пользователем, с временными данными, в которые бы записывал его товары, которые он заказал, естественно, хранил бы IP, куки, и другие всевозможные идентификационные данные.

Как только он захотел зайти за пользователя, предложил бы ему перенести введенные данные под анонимом. Так же при прохождении регистрации (а тут регистрация уже сводится к редактированию полей данных типо *Логин*, *e-mail*, *пароль*) эти данные о его товарах сохранял бы.

Comment: Мысль неплохая, плюсую может кто еще что-то скажет?

Comment: Вот действительно идея хорошая, но я думаю, что хранить пользователя надо в отделеьной таблице, в ней и указать все параметры переданные браузером, и отправить человеку кукисы с ид временного пользователя к примеру. Потом мне то никто не мешает завести отдельное свойство для товара для временных пользователей. Таким образом я не нарушаю уже сделанную ACL на сайте и просто идентифицирую пользователя. Как вы считаете @IVsevolod или я все-же ошибаюсь?

Comment: @binliz я предлагаю хранить временного пользователя в таблице всех пользователей, и работать с анонимом, как с пользователем. А вы предлагаете временного хранить совсем в другой таблице? В общем, я думаю вы мою идею поняли, и вы уже ее правильно дорабатываете. У вас все получиться :)

Comment: В общем то, что у меня получится я как бы и не сомневался еще не задавая тему. Но все же интересны мысли разных людей по поводу темы. Мне очень понравился ваш ответ. Потому и решил развить тему для более глубокого обсуждения. Но вижу никто включится не хочет. 
В общем то для пользователя в одной таблице есть некоторое ограничение: если их будет много, таблица реальных пользователей будет сильно фрагментировнная, чего в большом проекте я бы не хотел. Стает вопрос хранения таких данных т.е. сколько давать времени на раздумия о регистрации на сайте. Удаление не вернувшихся...

Answer (score 3):

Расскажу про свой давний опыт.

Для списка избранных товаров анонимным клиентом таблицу не использовал, избранные товары хранились непосредственно в самих куках. Перечисленные через точку ID товара.

Для зарегистрированных - список избранного хранился в отдельной таблице: ID_user => ID_item

При регистрации пользователя - данные из куки сохранялись в таблице, - кука уничтожалась.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут много решений... Если интернет магазин то можно каждому посетителю заливать куки с массивом, а если это какой то портал то надо ему заливать в куки случайно генирируемое слово (абракадабру) и вставлять это же слово с Id предметов в бд. Ip адрес у большинства динамический так что не всегда прокатит

Answer (score 1):

[@istem](/users/1254/istem) уже написал про куки - это наилучший вариант. 
Так же, можно каждому вошедшему давать уникальный номер(короткий), который будет хранится в базе данных и будет содержать избранные гостиницы.

К примеру я получил №456 , мне на экран вылезло, типо записать и тд. И все данные записываются в БД по этому номеру.

Так же можно просто сохранять все посещения и избранные, и дать пользователю короткую ссылку, чтобы он мог пройти(если куки удалились) и все избранные снова залезли в куки.

Вариантов множество. Выбор за Вами.